# A question about the Lotka-Volterra model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This problem is from Teschl's Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems, problem 7.2 on page 203:

Show that for any orbit of the Volterra-Lotka system

\begin{align}
\dot{x(t)} & = (1-y)x \\
\dot{y(t)} & = \alpha(x-1)y, \ \ \ \alpha > 0
\end{align}

the time average over one period
$$\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}x(t)dt = 1, \ \ \ \ \ \frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}y(t)dt = 1$$
is independent of the orbit (Hint: Integrate $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\text{ln}(x(t))$ over one period).

My approach so far: I tried to use the hint and integrated $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\text{ln}(x(t))$ over one period which gave me
$$\int_{0}^{T}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\text{ln}(x(t))dt = \text{ln}(x(T)) - \text{ln}(x(0))$$

but I am stuck here right now and I don't know how to continue with the exercise. Can anyone maybe help me?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

From the first of the two differential equations of the system, you have
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\ln(x(t))=\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)}=(1-y(t))\ .
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\int_0^T(1-y(t))\,dt&=\int_0^T\frac{d}{dt}\ln(x(t))dt\\
&=\ln(x(T))-\ln(x(0))\ .
\end{align}
If $\ T\ $ is the period, what can you say about the relation between $\ x(0)\ $ and $\ x(T)\ $?

Comment: Since $\int_{0}^{T}(1-y(t))dt = \int_{0}^{T}1dt - \int_{0}^{T}y(t)dt= T - T = 0 = \text{ln}(x(T)) - \text{ln}(x(0))$ we have $\text{ln}(x(T)) = \text{ln}(x(0))$ and therefore $x(T) = x(0)$. Since $x(t)$ was chosen arbitrarily, we have shown for $\textbf{all}$ orbits, that $x(T) = x(0)$. But how do I conclude from that, that the average time period is independent of the orbit? I don't really understand that point so far.